# Index not found in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to solve a reinforcement learning problem with a simple q learning algorithme.
I must add a new state to my table if the agent don't already know it.
The probleme I have is that when I learn the new state, I have the folowing error: `'None of [x] are in the [index]'`

I did a little test code to understand what's happening and solve the problems when I encounter one but I don't find solution to this one.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

actions = [0, 1]
obs = (0)


q_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=actions)


def check_state_exist(state):
    global q_table
    if state not in q_table.index:
        # append new state to q table
        q_table = q_table.append(
            pd.Series(
                [0]*len(actions),
                index=q_table.columns,
                name=state,
            )
        )
def choose_action(state):
    global actions
    check_state_exist(state)
    # action selection
    if np.random.uniform() < 0.9:
        # choose best action
        state_action = q_table.loc[state, :]
        state_action = state_action.reindex(np.random.permutation(state_action.index))     # some actions have same value
        action = np.argmax(state_action)
    else:
        # choose random action
        action = np.random.choice(actions)
    return action


for i in range(50):

    rand = random.randrange(100)
    if rand == 1:
        obs = 'rare'
    else: 
        obs = [rand, random.randrange(10)]
        obs = tuple(obs)

    choose_action(obs)
```

'None of [(56, 5)] are in the [index]'

```
print(q_table)

         0  1
(56, 5)  0  0
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

When you use a tuple as index, pandas will automatically behave like multi-indexing. If you want to index with `(56,5)` in a solo-level-index, you might want to try something like `q_table.loc[[(56,5)]]` (not sure if it works though). Otherwise, as it makes sense in Q-learning, you can try using a multi-index.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some hours of test, I finally solve the problem. Instead of using a tuple, I used a string.
I gess it's because .loc was trying to find the number of the index and not the name of the index.